# Safari parsing JSON-LD error on 'telephone' ('Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,"telephone")')

Tags: safari, sentry, json-ld, structured-data

Since we enabled Sentry for our application front-end, which we build with TALL stack, we get a lot of errors from Safari browsers. Which I cannot replicate.

First we got the error like this [Safari throws when parsing JSON-LD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76995140/safari-throws-when-parsing-json-ld), which we solved and could find it in the Safari console (but sometimes pops up in Sentry).

But now we get the following error which I cant replicate.

```
TypeError - extractSchemaValuesFromJSONLD

null is not an object (evaluating 'Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,"telephone")')
```

I validated the schema and everything is okay, I added a phone number to the organization, which does not solve it. It does not happen if I remove the complete schema.

No where on internet can I find anything about this, only occurrence is here;
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/61469

It only on Safari (mobile & desktop), with different devices & versions.

How can I fix or at least replicate this problem?